# Unable to build string in ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

I am currently working on building a few templates for some of the basic deployments that I use daily and have them working except for the last piece. The issue is that i am using t-shirt sizing to choose a specific vhd as I am deploying and I can not see to get the syntax correct for the uri string.

I know the syntax to call the variable on its own but when I add it into the uri string, it fails.

`[variables(‘vhd’)[parameters('version')]]`

Parameter:

`"version": {
     "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "10.5",
      "allowedValues": [
          "10.3.1",
          "10.4.1",
          "10.5"
       ],`

Variable:

`"vhd": {
      "10.3.1": "20170524144905.vhd", 
       "10.4.1": "20170524144656.vhd", 
       "10.5": "20170524133408.vhd"
       },`

String:

`"vhd": {
     "uri": "[concat(concat(reference(resourceId(parameters('virtualMachineName'), 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageAccountName')), '2015-06-15').primaryEndpoints['blob'], 'vhds/'), parameters('virtualMachineName'), '20170524133408.vhd')]"
      },`

Comment: Just figured it out...It should be `"uri": "[concat(concat(reference(resourceId(parameters('virtualMachineName'), 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageAccountName')), '2015-06-15').primaryEndpoints['blob'], 'vhds/'), parameters('virtualMachineName'), variables('vhd')[parameters('version')])]"`

Comment: According to your description, it seems that you want to select a specific vhd in the storage account , uri should be like `https://shuitest1disks432.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/shui20170517164826.vhd`